# Two the same type arguments in one class method in Python

Tags: python, methods, arguments

How to declare two the same type of arguments in one class method in Python:

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print("I am A")

class B(object):
    def test(self, A): #def test(self, A, A): -> of course doesn't work
        A.test()

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
b = B()
b.test(a1)
#b.test(a1, a2)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the question and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Python is __dynamic__ typing language. It means that you cannot force data type on argument (you may add type checking). Your _A_ argument in test method is an independent argument whose type is defined at execution time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `A` as parameter names. You can use any name. For example `a1` and `a2`:

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print("I am A")

class B(object):
    def test(self, a1, a2):
        a1.test()
        a2.test()

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
b = B()
b.test(a1, a2)
```

You wrote *class method*. These are special methods in Python. The normal methods you use in your example are called as *instance methods* or simply *methods*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going for here, but:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print ("I am %s" % cls.__name__)

class B(object):
    def test(self, *args):
         for arg in args:
             arg.test()
```

should work...

Also note that `B.test` doesn't use `self` at all, it could be a `staticmethod`, but the usual advice applies when using staticmethods (ask yourself if there is an advantage to having a staticmethod instead of just a module level function).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but looks like the OP is trying to implement method overloading...